# Load angular form using Ajax then Bind md-select after this show error

Tags: angularjs

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'mdSelectMenu', required by directive 'mdOption', can't be found!

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq

Answer (score 0):

Use **`<md-select>`** instead of **`md-selectmenu`**.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('materialApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="materialApp">
  <md-select class="width-100" placeholder="Quantity" data-ng-model="task.qty">
    <md-option value="one">One</md-option>
    <md-option value="two">Two</md-option>
    <md-option value="three">Three</md-option>
    <md-option value="four">Four</md-option>
    <md-option value="five">Five</md-option>
  </md-select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `<md-option>` element is only allowed to be used as a child of an `<md-select>` element:

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a state">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

The `<md-select>` element is required.